# Clone form with tabs and dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to clone a form with tabs. Every cloned instance has a number asigned. 1, 2 etc for every clone, incrementing. Every tab of the clone has the href attribute dymamically generated.

links have href attributes like this

```html
<li class="active">
 <a href="#enInfo" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
</li>
<li> 
 <a href="#spInfo" data-toggle="tab">Inicio</a>
</li>
```

for tab-pane divs, same ids

```html
<div class="tab-pane active" id="enInfo">English content</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="spInfo">Contenido en espanol</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to find the href attribute of every  element (enInfo, spInfo) and generate the same ids for "tab pane" div. The desired result for the cloned form should be, (#enInfo2, #spInfo2) for first clone, (#enInfo3, #spInfo3) for second clone and so on.

```html
<li class="active">
  <a href="#enInfo2" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
</li>
<li> 
  <a href="#spInfo2" data-toggle="tab">Inicio</a>
</li>
```

and

```html
<div class="tab-pane active" id="enInfo2">English content</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="spInfo2">Contenido en espanol</div>
```

Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="sections">
  <div class="section">

    <h6>New stream</h6>


<div class="tab-group">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#enInfo" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#spInfo" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="enInfo">English content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="spInfo">Contenido en espanol</div>
  </div>
</div>


   <p><a href="#" class='remove'>Remove</a></p>

  </div>
</div>

<p><a href="#" class='addsection'>Add</a></p>



<script type="text/javascript" >
//define template
var template = $('#sections .section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;


//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find('.tab-group').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        //var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;
        var newId = sectionsCount;

        //update id parent
        this.id = newId;


        $(this).prev().text('New stream ' + newId);


        $(this).parent().find('span').attr("id", + newId);
        $(this).parent().find('a').attr("href", + newId);


    }).end()


    //inject new section
    .appendTo('#sections');
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('#sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().empty(); // $(this).parent().parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
</script>




    </body>
</html>
```

I guess I have to loop somehow the elements but don't know how, my jQuery, Javascript skills are limited and even after hours and hours of tests, can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right you will need to loop over each element (navlinks and tab-panes) to update the attributes. Here is the stack snippet that serves what you are looking for.

```js
//define template
var template = $('#sections .section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;


//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each tab-group if more than one
    var section = template.clone().find('.tab-group').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = sectionsCount; 
    
        // set jquery elements
        const $this = $(this);
        const $sectionHeader = $this.prev();
        const $navLinks = $this.find('.nav-tabs li');
        const $tabPanes = $this.find('.tab-content .tab-pane');
        
        // set section header
        $sectionHeader.text($sectionHeader.text() + ' ' + newId);
        
        // set attributes for nav links
        $navLinks.each(function() {
         const $anchor = $(this).find('a').first();
          $anchor.attr('href', $anchor.attr('href') + newId);
        });
        
        // set attributes for tab panes
        $tabPanes.each(function() {
          $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + newId);
        });
    }).end()


    //inject new section
    .appendTo('#sections');
    
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('#sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().empty(); // $(this).parent().parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sections">
  <div class="section">

    <h6>New stream</h6>


<div class="tab-group">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#enInfo" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#spInfo" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="enInfo">English content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="spInfo">Contenido en espanol</div>
  </div>
</div>


   <p><a href="#" class='remove'>Remove</a></p>

  </div>
</div>

<p><a href="#" class='addsection'>Add</a></p>
```